# Error android studio no puede encontrar linea

Tags: android

me aparece esto al agregar los datos que da firebase para la implementacion[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Bienvenido al sitio pauuu, te invito a realizar el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento básico del sitio. Con respecto a la realización de preguntas que estas sean bien recibidas por la comunidad y obtengas excelentes respuestas, **es muy importante leer [ask]** , saludos!

Comment: podrias poner el codigo que se encuentra en tu build.gradle a nivel de proyecto? el error se encuentra en ese archivo

Answer (score 0):

Comprueba que estes usando las versiones correctas de cada dependencia por ejemplo, trata sustituyendo:

`implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.0'`

por:

`implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:15.0.0'`

Si el error continua, comprueba que hayas añadido el repositorio maven de google:

```
url "https://maven.google.com" // Google's Maven repository
```

Comment: cambiar a una versión anterior!!!??? de 16.0.0 a 15.0.0

Comment: Si, dentro de la [documentacion](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup?hl=es-419), la implementacion aparece con 15 y tu lo tienes con 16 posiblemente ese sea tu error

Answer (score -1):

La solucion es agregar esto en tu build.gradle del proyecto (no modulo)

```
buildscript {
    // ...
    dependencies {
        // ...
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1' // google-services plugin
    }
}

allprojects {
    // ...
    repositories {
        // ...
        google() // Google's Maven repository
    }
}
```

Comment: ¿Que realiza si se agrega esto?

Comment: @Jorgesys realizaría la solución (?)

Comment: lo que hacen esas lineas es: google() agrega el repositorio Maven de Google como repositorio en donde buscar las dependencias y classpath 'com.google.gm....' agrega una dependencia sobre un plugin